# Do uniformly grey sets of positive density exist?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

Let us call a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ *uniformly grey* if the measure of its sections is constant, but not full. (There may be a standard name for this; I would be glad if someone tells me.)

Formal definition: There are intervals $[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ and constants $\mu_1\in(0,\lambda(A_2))$ and $\mu_2\in(0,\lambda(A_1))$ such that  $\lambda(\{x_2:(x_1,x_2)\in A\}) = \mu_1$ for any $x_1\in (\inf a_1,b_1)$ and $\lambda(\{x_1:(x_1,x_2)\in A\}) = \mu_2$ for any $x_2\in (a_2, b_2)$; $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

A simple example is $A = \{(x_1,x_2)\in[0,1]^2: (x_2-x_1)\mod 1\in(0,1/2)\}$.

Well, this does not look grey at all, so in order to make it look grey, let us add an assumption of *positive density*: for any $x = (x_1,x_2)\in (a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)$ and any $r>0$, $\lambda_2(B(x,r)\cap A)>0$, where $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

So the question is:

> Does there exist a uniformly grey set of positive density?

Comment: there are many typos/errors in the question statement. regardless, it seems you have solved this question in the comments below. you should post an answer and mark it accepted, so people know this question has been resolved

Comment: @mathworker21, please feel free to edit the typos and to answer the question; I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a fat Cantor set $C$ (such as the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set) in $[0,1]$ of measure $\frac{1}{2}$. Then $C \times C$ will satisfy your section condition.

Does it have positive density? The points in the fat cantor set have positive density on $\mathbb{R}$, and so given any ball around our point we can find a square within that ball having positive intersection with our set.

Comment: This is not uniformly grey. However, seems that $A = \{(x_1,x_2): (x_1 - x_2)\mod 1\in C\}$ works. Didn't guess it would be so simple.

Comment: Why is it not uniformly grey? Each section has measure 1/2.

Comment: Sorry, asked it wrong...

Comment: Fair enough, I misinterpreted full measure as being full measure in the square, not each section being full measure in the projection.

Comment: I've corrected the question. Sorry for such mess. Still it seems that something like $\{(x_1,x_2): (x_1 - x_2) \mod 1\in C\}$ with $C$ of density between $0$ and $1$ works.